# Toshiba windows 7 laptop, all icons the same

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, icons, start-menu

all desktop icons the same and when I try to open it says this action is valid for products that are already installed. when I enter regedit in the search it says the same thing so i can't even fix it with this solution because everything I try to open says the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to spyware or a virus. Your best bet at the moment is to download HitMan Pro and create a bootable usb drive of it (use another pc if you have to, to create the usb drive). Then boot from the usb stick with hitman pro and scan for malware. When it repairs the problem reboot once more and everything should be fine again.

Alternatively (but much harder) download Hirens boot dvd/cd, burn the disc or put on a USB drive, boot from it and try and repair it manually from there.